# ROO: how to create composite primary key in Entity

Tags: oracle, spring-roo

What can I do if I need to create entity for
a table in production DB (Oracle 10g) with composite primary key.

For example:
[CODE]

```
CREATE TABLE TACCOUNT
(
  BRANCHID     NUMBER(3)                        NOT NULL,
  ACC          VARCHAR2(18 BYTE)                NOT NULL,
  DATE_OPEN    DATE                             NOT NULL,
  DATE_CLOSE   DATE,
  NOTE         VARCHAR2(38 BYTE)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PK_TACCOUNT ON TACCOUNT
(BRANCHID, ACC);
```

I don't want to change the structure of this table.

Is it possible to create an "id" field using roo commands?

I use Spring Roo 1.0.2.RELEASE [rev 638]